Ubuntu 20.04 login not working after backing up Proxmox VM
I have a Lubuntu 20.04 LTS VM running on my Proxmox 8.2.5 server. It was configured to auto-login at boot, as it is running on a headless server. Today I stopped the VM to do a snapshot backup from the Proxmox console (to a local SATA SSD). When I restarted the VM it did not auto-login - it prompted me for a user id and password. My user name and password were rejected, however - when I enter them I get bounced back to the login box. I am only able to login as root.
If I do "cat /etc/passwd" I can see my user in the list. If I try to open "Users and Groups" from the UI the application hangs.
Most of the services seems to have started (e.g. Home Assistant, SMB), but for some reason Logitech Media Server will not start - and does not generate any output in the log when I try to start it from the command line.
Any idea why this has happened, and how I can restore my login access and auto-login?

I figured it out - I was low on disk space (6GB remaining). Freeing up a little space resolved the problem
